# Facebook SDK giving unused variable compile errors in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting a lot of unused variable errors after updating to the new version of and Xcode 5.1.

Compiler is saying unused variables are errors, and checked the compiler settings that i didn't modify treating warning as errors.

This only happened after I updated to Xcode 5.1

Comment: I use Facebook SDK version 3.12.0 and I have not problem after xCode 5.1 migration. Which version of FB SDK? Besides it should work, unused variable it's not error, it's warning.

Comment: Facebook use Treat Warnings as Errors flag - hence if you use their project and not compile their source code inside yours or the precompiled framework - you will encounter this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be indeed an issue with Facebook iOS SDK and compiling on Xcode 5.1 even if compiling it by itself.
I opened a bug in the Facebook support system:
https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/1449419898627543/

As a temporary workaround - you can fix it by turning off treating warnings as errors ( a very good practice by itself btw I use for our SDK) by:
1. Open the Facebook proj file (or the project inside an existing project
2. Go to build settings of the entire project
3. Change the "Treat Warnings as Errors" field from YES to NO.

This will let you compile it even with these warnings - but do be alert for an updated sdk in the coming days.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that we were unintentionally compiling for 64bit in the internal compiler settings somewhere inside our scripts.  Please be aware.

Comment: Facebook iOS SDK by itself doesn't seem to compile due to unused variables.
While you might have solved the issue for yourself - it's not a solution in the long run and they will have to fix it.

Comment: Do note - Facebook has updated the bug I opened and acknowledged the issue. Working with warnings or compiling in 32 bit is hardly a solution , more like an ugly patch. This means you compile Facebook code inside your app (like cocoa pods does and not as a sub module) - the problem still is there once you will move to support arm64 devices.